# How can I print a line after another line that uses a str variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Struggling to get the correct output needed. so far this is my code

```
def main():
    move_on = 'y'
    golfScoreFile = open('golfRecords.txt', 'a')
    while move_on == 'y' or move_on == 'Y':
        pName = input("Enter the player's name: ")
        pScore = int(input("Enter the player's score: "))
        golfScoreFile.write(pName + "\n")
        golfScoreFile.write(str(pScore) + "\n")
        move_on = input("Would you like to continue? [y]: ")
    displayRecords = input("Would you like to display all the records from golfRecords.txt? [y]: ")
    golfScoreFile.close()
    if (displayRecords == 'y' or displayRecords == 'Y'):
        displayRecs()
    else:
        searchRecs()


def displayRecs():
    golfScoreFile = open('golfRecords.txt', 'r')
    lineCount = 1
    for line in golfScoreFile:
        golfRecLine = lineCount % 2
        if (golfRecLine == 0):
            print("The score of this person is: ", line)
        if (golfRecLine == 1):
            print("The name of this person is: ", line)
        lineCount = lineCount + 1
    golfScoreFile.close()


def searchRecs():
    search = input("Enter player name: ")
    golfScoreFile = open('golfRecords.txt', 'r')
    logs = golfScoreFile.read()
    if search in logs:
        golfScoreFile.close()
        file = open('golfRecords.txt', 'r')
        for x in file:
            if search in x:
                





main()
```

Specifically look at the def searchRecs() function. i need to look up the name i input from the main function and get the score i put that is associated with the name. I then need to print both of these inputs. I have to have different functions for the assignment. I have tried a couple ways and i either get TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator or it just prints the name and not the score. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing the structure of your logs file...are the names and scores separated by tabs or something?

Also, `read()` doesnt return list of lines. you want to use `readlines()` and store that in a variable, that will create a list of lines you can iterate over.

Also, proper software design principles state that a function should do 1 thing. You shouldn't have a function to return both the score and the name. You could alternatively just return the whole line and have another function process that line accordingly.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!